# Spring Security and Action Required after login

Tags: java, session, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement an action required screen after user is logged-in in Spring Security? I have a requirement where user has to perform to complete a form (change password, accept Terms Of Use, etc.), then once user completes that action he can use the rest of the app. I'm using Spring OAuth2 with the login screen that uses Spring Security flow.

So far I have tried to use `http.formLogin().successHandler()` that has custom implementation of `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, which detects if user has action required, then redirects user to the page when he can fill out the form, but the problem with that is that if user navigates away from that page, he will be logged in to the app and can use it without by skipping the form. But what I'm trying to do is to block user from establishing the session until after that Action Required form is complete. Once it is complete user should be automatically logged in (ex. if user was req. to only agree with Terms of Use, he should be logged in without entering a password second time)

Here is the code that I have so far the custom handler:

```
public class CustomLoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    public final static String TARGET_URL_SESSION_ATTR_NAME = "target-url";

    public CustomLoginSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl) {
        setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultTargetUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        AuthorityUser authorityUser = (AuthorityUser)authentication.getPrincipal();

        String userId = authorityUser.getUserId();

        User u = userService.getById(userId);

        Boolean changeRequiredDob = u.getChangeRequiredDob();
        Boolean changeRequiredPwd = u.getChangeRequiredPwd();
        Boolean changeRequiredTou = u.getChangeRequiredTou();

        if(changeRequiredDob || changeRequiredPwd || changeRequiredTou){

            String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response);
            session.setAttribute(TARGET_URL_SESSION_ATTR_NAME, targetUrl);
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/action-required");
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

And then once it is successfully complete I'm redirecting user to `TARGET_URL_SESSION_ATTR_NAME` that was stored to the session.

It would be also helpful to know how to detect and redirect user to the action required screen during the established sessions (if user logged in and later while he is logged in admin sets action required flag on his account).

Comment: Implementing this logic in an ordinary filter (mapped to /*) fulfills both your requrements: a) user wont be able to navigate away from it, and b) user will be automatically "logged-in", or rather passed through. Only additional thing you may need to implement is proper redirect on success.

Comment: Is there an actual reason that you dont want to create session right away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/king-julien/spring-oauth2-customfilter Here is a working sample with Authorization and Resource Server. This Resource Server (vanilla) is a basic stateless application which will not proceed any further until you accept Terms of Service (to accept TOS, Just a do a POST on /tos end point) after authentication.

## Create a filter

```
@Component
public class TosFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());

        // In realworld scenario HelloWorldController.acceptedTOS is a persisted value rather than a static variable
        if(!HelloWorldController.acceptedTOS){
            //response.sendRedirect("/no-tos");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("error-no-tos").forward(request, response);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

---

## Register that filter

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    TosFilter rolesFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{

        httpSecurity
                .addFilterAfter(rolesFilter, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

---

## Annotate your main with @EnableResourceServer.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way we solve that is to have the OAuth2 approval page be a single page application. 
By default the approval page controller is WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint. We override this by defining out own OauthApproval Controller which overrides "/oauth/confirm_access", so we can add extra stuff to the model. When the approval (jsp) page is loaded, we convert some of the model properties into javascript variables (var token = '${_csrf.token}';), and start an AngularJS application. The approval page can then do whatever it wants (before showing the actual approval form), we just need to build REST endpoints for the different functionalities.

Remember to add @SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest") to the Controller

Comment: Im not familliar with OAuth2 but isnt this mean that custom action must be handled by authorization server instead of resource server?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` you should use filter:

```
public class ActionRequirementCheckingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    /* This matcher should not match static resources (js,css etc),
     * url`s needed to handle the action and possibly something else,
     * depending on your application */
    private RequestMatcher matcher;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Boolean actionRequired = false;

        /* calculate actual value for actionRequired */

        if(matcher.matches(request) && actionRequired){

            /* save current request info into session for later use if needed */

            response.sendRedirect("/action-required");
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

This approach fits all your requirments:

- User wont be able to navigate away from it
- User will be automatically logged-in after action is complete
- It will even work for existing sessions

Only drawback is that session will be actualy created before action is completed, but unless you have a real reason not to do that (which i cant even imaging) this is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of verifying user access rights during a successfully logged in session is via the filter api

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/

You can then implement the functionality needed in the doFilter() to verify your rules.